# How to make a button with onTapDown, onTapUp and onHover functions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-widget

I want to create a button to do something when it is onTapDown, onTapUp, and show a tool tip when it is onHover.

I learned the GestureDetector can achieve **onTapDown**, **onTapUp**, so I made the following code.

```
GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (details) => print('onTapDown'),
            onTapUp: (details) => print('onTapUp'),
            child: const Tooltip(
              message: 'onHover',
              child: Icon(
                Icons.help,
                size: 40,
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

It works well with onHover and onTapDown part, but it didn't run the **onTapUp** part of code somehow. I guess tooltip may have some conflicts with GestureDetector, but I don't know how to fix it.

Could anyone know how to implement a button can do onTapDown, onTapUp and onHover at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine on dartpad just changed the Counter example and added your gesture detector snippet as it is

Answer (score 1):

`onTapUp` is executed when you simply tap the button and lift your finger, this is the order: `onTapDown` - `onTapUp` - `onTap`.

If you tap the button, keep it pressed, then move your finger away, the tap is considered to be canceled, there is an `onTapCancel` event for this case. In this case you will have: `onTapDown` - `onTapCancel` in this order.

There are a lot of events `GestureDetecture` handles, check [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Peter, Your answer helps me understand how tap works in GestureDetector.

I figured out that using **onTapCancel** instead of **onTapUp** won't cause the conflict with Tooltip(Since it will not end up causing a tap).

I changed the code as follows to achieve the feature. It uses a button with Tooltip message to open and close a page. Click once => open page, Click again => close page

```
   GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (details) => print('open page'),
            onTapCancel: () => print('close page'),
            child: const Tooltip(
              message: 'onHover',
              child: Icon(
                Icons.help,
                size: 40,
                color: Colors.black26,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```